# C# locate and return string in List<t>

Tags: c#

I have a `List<Borrower>` called BorrowerList. I want to be able to find and return a string value (`name`) from the list. The solution from a similar question does not work for me (uses Linq)

```
public Borrower FindBorrower(string name)
{
     var match = BorrowerList.FirstOrDefault(stringToCheck => stringToCheck.Contains(name));
     // error raised here says: does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload
     return match;
}
```

If it helps this is the code for `Borrower`

```
class Borrower
{
    private string name;
    private Book b;

    public Borrower(string n)
    {
        name = n;
    }

    public string GetName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public Book GetBook()
    {
        return b;
    }

    public void SetBook(Book b)
    {
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried it, didn't work. Says that stringToCheck doesn't exist in current context

Comment: That seems to me to be a blind copy / paste of the code I provided. I did not provide the entire set of code to be pasted in, just the bit that needed fixing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error comes from your `Borrower` class, it does not have a `Contains` method.

It appears that you have unsuccessfully transposed a solution that would work for a `List<string>` to your `List<Borrower>`.

The simplest fix is:

```
var match = BorrowerList.FirstOrDefault(borrower => borrower.Name.Contains(name));
```

This assumes you add a `string Name {get;}` property to `Borrower`. If not, then...

```
var match = BorrowerList.FirstOrDefault(borrower => borrower.GetName().Contains(name));
```

...should suffice.

---

By way of an explanation, the signature `FirstOrDefault` is a `Func<T, bool>`. In this case `T` is `Borrower`, not `string`, so you need drill into the properties / methods of `Borrower` to get the name.

There are, perhaps, nicer solutions to this problem. For the time being though, this should get you past the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

If i guess right that was your intention:

```
    public Borrower FindBorrower(string name)
    {
        var match = BorrowerList.Where(x => x.nameToCheck.Contains(name)).FirstOrDefault();
        return match;
    }

}

class Borrower
{
    public string nameToCheck { get; set; }
    // the rest of class definitions...
}
```

Comment: This could make use of the overload for `FirstOrDefault` that takes a condition predicate.